# How can I install data.table on my fedora distro

Tags: python, python-3.x, py-datatable

Looking at [this github](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable) I'd like to be able to install `datatable`.
I do run a `fedora 26` distro that runs `python3.6`

```
statquant  ~  python3
Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar 13 2018, 18:16:01) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180130 (Red Hat 7.3.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

When I try to install it I get:

```
statquant  ~  pip install https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/datatable/stable/datatable-0.3.2/datatable-0.3.2-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
datatable-0.3.2-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Is this expected ?
I am totally new to python

Answer (score 3):

Currently Python `datatable` distributes pre-built binaries for the following platforms:

- MacOS
- CentOS Linux (linux_x86_64)
- PowerPC Linux (ppc64le)

For all other platforms, you would have to clone the repository and manually [build from source](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/wiki/Build-instructions).

Comment: It might work, but `pip` doesn't know that. It looks at the name of the wheel file, sees that it contains `linux_x86_64`, and concludes that the wheel is not suitable for your platform. It *might* be possible to trick `pip` by renaming the wheel file, but that is definitely a hacky approach.